# Logging to different files based on logger name in log4j.xml

Tags: java, xml, logging, log4j

I wanted to log the message into the files based on **only logger name** that i specified, as logger name is sent as a parameter in log message. By default all my log files are getting appended irrespective of logger name, as i have added ref of all appenders under root.

My log4j.xml is as below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration SYSTEM "log4j.dtd">
<log4j:configuration debug="true">
<!-- ========== appenders start here ========= -->

<appender name="operator_log" class="org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender">
    <param name="ImmediateFlush" value="true" />
    <param name="Append" value="true" />
    <param name="File" value="C:/SSG_Admin.log" />
    <param name="DatePattern" value="'.'yyyy-MM-dd" />
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
        <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{DATE}|%5p|%m%n" />
    </layout>
</appender>

<appender name="security_log" class="org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender">
    <param name="ImmediateFlush" value="true" />
    <param name="Append" value="true" />
    <param name="File" value="C:/SSG_Security.log" />
    <param name="DatePattern" value="'.'yyyy-MM-dd" />
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
        <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{DATE}|%5p|%m%n" />
    </layout>
</appender>

<appender name="application_log" class="org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender">
    <param name="ImmediateFlush" value="true" />
    <param name="Append" value="true" />
    <param name="File" value="C:/SSG_Core.log" />
    <param name="DatePattern" value="'.'yyyy-MM-dd" />
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
        <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{DATE}|%5p|%m%n" />
    </layout>
</appender>

<!-- ========= loggers start here ========= -->
<logger name="DB_CONNECTION_ISSUE" additivity="false">
    <level value="debug" />
    <appender-ref ref="operator_log" />
    <appender-ref ref="application_log" />
</logger>
<logger name="NETWORK_ISSUE" additivity="false">
    <level value="debug" />
    <appender-ref ref="operator_log" />
    <appender-ref ref="application_log" />
</logger>
<logger name="COMMUNICATION_ISSUE" additivity="false">
    <level value="debug" />
    <appender-ref ref="operator_log" />
    <appender-ref ref="application_log" />
</logger>
<logger name="ACCESS_ISSUES" additivity="false">
    <level value="debug" />
    <appender-ref ref="security_log" />
    <appender-ref ref="application_log" />
</logger>
<logger name="CERTIFICATE_ISSUE" additivity="false">
    <level value="debug" />
    <appender-ref ref="security_log" />
    <appender-ref ref="application_log" />
</logger>

<logger name="VALIDATION_OR_DATA_ISSUE" additivity="false">
    <level value="debug" />
    <appender-ref ref="application_log" />
</logger>
<logger name="OTHER_ISSUE" additivity="false">
    <level value="debug" />
    <appender-ref ref="application_log" />
</logger>

<root>
    <priority value="debug" />
    <appender-ref ref="operator_log" />
    <appender-ref ref="security_log" />
    <appender-ref ref="application_log" />
</root>
```

The specified appenders under loggers only should append the respective files for me. but, all files getting appended irrespective of logger name.
I am very new to loggers. Is there any solution for this...

Comment: Could you please check if "category" is helpful for you? category uses "appender-ref" where you van mention the file name.

Answer (score 0):

Could you please check with "category"? Following is an example :

```
<appender name="myFile" class="org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender">
    <param name="Threshold" value="INFO" />
    <param name="File" value="/abc/logs/myLog.log"/>
    <param name="Append" value="true" />
    <param name="MaxFileSize" value="10MB" />
    <param name="MaxBackupIndex" value="100" />
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
        <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%r %d %-5p  [%c{1}] %m %n" />
    </layout>
</appender>

<category name="com.myFile.crs" additivity="false">
    <priority value="info" />
    <appender-ref ref="myFile" />
</category>
```

Comment: <appender-ref ref="myFile" />        what is myFile in this ?? appender name u have given as  <appender name="file" class="org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender">

Comment: Thanks for the response, I changed my <logger> to <category> still the problem remains same..

Comment: No. Changing the logger to category will not work. name="com.myFile.crs" is the package name of the java classes who should log.

Comment: My loggers are not restricted to particular classes. logger name I have given is a **parameter** that will be sent in **logMessage()** method that is present in several classes...    The **parameter**  is the one which decides which appender should be used to log respective file .

Comment: Please provide the details. That will help others.